# Can a bash script distinguish between being called as a script and being run as a "source"?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that has inside it:

```
exit 1
```

When I "source" this script instead of running it, it causes the caller to exit.

Is there a way that the script can determine that it's being run with "source" and not as its script?

Comment: See [BashFAQ/109 (How can I tell whether my script was sourced (dotted in) or executed?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/109)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this check inside your script:

```
[[ $0 = $BASH_SOURCE ]] && echo "normal run" || echo "sourced run"
```

Or using `if/else/fi` wherever you're calling `exit`:

```
if [[ $0 = $BASH_SOURCE ]]; then
   exit 1
else
   # don't call exit
   echo "some error..."
fi
```